# R extension in C, setting matrix row/column names

Tags: c, r, matrix

I'm writing an R package that manipulates Matrices in C.  Currently, the matrices returned to R have numbers for the row/column names.  I would rather assign my own row/column names when modifying the object in C.

I've googled around for about an hour, but haven't found a good solution yet.  The closest I've found is dimnames, but I want to name each column, not just the two dimensions.  The matrices get larger than 4x4, below is just a small example of what I want to do.

The number of rows is 4^x where X is the length of the row name

```
Current
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 0.20 0.00 0.00 0.80
[2,] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
[3,] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
[4,] 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
[5,] 0.20 0.00 0.00 0.80
[6,] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
[7,] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
[8,] 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
[9,] 0.20 0.00 0.00 0.80
[10,] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
[11,] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
[12,] 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
[13,] 0.20 0.00 0.00 0.80
[14,] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
[15,] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
[16,] 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00

Desired
     [A] [C] [G] [T]
 [AA] 0.20 0.00 0.00 0.80
 [AC] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
 [AG] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
 [AT] 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
 [CA] 0.20 0.00 0.00 0.80
 [CC] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
 [CG] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
 [CT] 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
 [GA] 0.20 0.00 0.00 0.80
 [GC] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
 [GG] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
 [GT] 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
 [TA] 0.20 0.00 0.00 0.80
 [TC] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
 [TG] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
 [TT] 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
```

Comment: dimnames does name each row and column, which a cursory glance at ?dimnames will show  dimnames(mat) <- list(c("A", "C", "G", "T"), c("A", "C", "G", "T"))  there is also ?rownames and ?colnames

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jim said, this is much easier to do in R.  I'm passing the names into the C function via the `nam` argument.

```
#include <Rinternals.h>
SEXP myMat(SEXP nam) {
  /*PrintValue(nam);*/
  SEXP ans, dimnames;
  PROTECT(ans = allocMatrix(REALSXP, length(nam), length(nam)));
  PROTECT(dimnames = allocVector(VECSXP, 2));
  SET_VECTOR_ELT(dimnames, 0, nam);
  SET_VECTOR_ELT(dimnames, 1, nam);
  setAttrib(ans, R_DimNamesSymbol, dimnames);
  UNPROTECT(2);
  return(ans);
}
```

If you put that code in a file called `myMat.c`, you can test it via the line below.  I'm using Ubuntu, so you will have to change `myMat.so` to `myMat.dll` if you're on Windows.

```
R CMD SHLIB myMat.c
Rscript -e 'dyn.load("myMat.so"); .Call("myMat", c("A","C","G","T"))'
```

Comment: Hmm, well, the issue is getting the strings into the SEXP objects.  PROTECT(colnames = allocVector(VECSXP, 4));
 PROTECT(A = NEW_CHARACTER(1));
    SET_STRING_ELT(A, 0, mkChar("A"));
    SET_VECTOR_ELT(rownames, 0, A);
    SET_VECTOR_ELT(rownames, 1, A);
    SET_VECTOR_ELT(rownames, 2, A);
    SET_VECTOR_ELT(rownames, 3, A);

Comment: Did you mean to say 'change "myMat.so" to "myMat.dll"? At the moment, the way it reads it seems like you are referring to `myMat.c` as the thing to change to `myMat.dll`.

Answer (score 6):

If you are open to C++ instead of C, then [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) can make this a little easier. We just create a list object with rows and column names as we would in R, and assign that to the `dimnames` attribute of the matrix object:

```
R> library(inline)                         # to compile, link, load the code here
R> src <- '
+   Rcpp::NumericMatrix x(2,2);
+   x.fill(42);                           // or more interesting values
+   // C++0x can assign a set of values to a vector, but we use older standard
+   Rcpp::CharacterVector rows(2); rows[0] = "aa"; rows[1] = "bb";
+   Rcpp::CharacterVector cols(2); cols[0] = "AA"; cols[1] = "BB";
+   // now create an object "dimnms" as a list with rows and cols
+   Rcpp::List dimnms = Rcpp::List::create(rows, cols);
+   // and assign it
+   x.attr("dimnames") = dimnms;
+   return(x);
+ '
R> fun <- cxxfunction(signature(), body=src, plugin="Rcpp")
R> fun()
   AA BB
aa 42 42
bb 42 42
R>
```

The actual assignment of the column and row names is so manual ... because the current C++ standard does not allow direct assignment of vectors at initialization, but that will change.

**Edit:** I just realized that I can of course use static `create()` method on the row and colnames too, which makes this a little easier and shorter still

```
R> src <- '
+   Rcpp::NumericMatrix x(2,2);
+   x.fill(42);                           // or more interesting values
+   Rcpp::List dimnms =                   // two vec. with static names
+       Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::CharacterVector::create("cc", "dd"),
+                          Rcpp::CharacterVector::create("ee", "ff"));
+   // and assign it
+   x.attr("dimnames") = dimnms;
+   return(x);
+ '
R> fun <- cxxfunction(signature(), body=src, plugin="Rcpp")
R> fun()
   ee ff
cc 42 42
dd 42 42
R>
```

So we are down to three or four statements, no monkeying with PROTECT / UNPROTECT and no memory management.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately I am limited to C.

Comment: Not really because every R installation that has C via gcc also has C++ via g++, and the object code interoperates.

Comment: Are there `.attr("rownames")`, `.attr("colnames")`, `.attr("names")` as well, in case one only wants to specify column or row names? Where would one find this information in the docs?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in, say, the R sources, or the sources of packages setting these things.

Answer (score 1):

The note above is instructive. The dimnames is a list with the same number of elements as dimensions of the dataset, where each element corresponds to the number elements along that dimension, i.e., `list(c('a','c','g','t'), c('a','c','g','t'))`.

To set that in C, I would recommend:

```
PROTECT(dimnames = allocVector(VECSXP, 2));
PROTECT(rownames = allocVector(STRSXP, 4));
PROTECT(colnames = allocVector(STRSXP, 4));
setAttrib( ? , R_DimNamesSymbol, dimnames);
```

You'll have to then set the relevant rowname and colname elements. In general, this stuff is *much* easier to do in R.

jim

Comment: You need to set the elements of `dimnames` before calling `setAttrib`.  @Nick: I'd also recommend doing this in R.

Comment: Jim, it'd need to be UNPROTECTED(4) as well.  I tried it out and it didn't seem to work.  I'll keep trying though

Comment: You also would need at least the following, but its still not working...     SET_STRING_ELT(rownames, 0, mkChar("A")); SET_VECTOR_ELT(dimnames, 0, rownames);
    SET_VECTOR_ELT(dimnames, 1, colnames);