# Setting *only* column names in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I want to set a matrix's column names only using Rcpp, but leave the row names unchanged.  So far as I can tell, the `dimnames` attribute only sets both.  For example:

- [R extension in C, setting matrix row/column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709940/r-extension-in-c-setting-matrix-row-column-names/5711326#5711326)
- http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf (p.13)

Here's a minimal example of what I want to do, but just in Rcpp instead of R:

```
my.mat <- diag(3)
colnames( my.mat ) <- c( "A", "B", "C")
my.mat
     A B C
[1,] 1 0 0
[2,] 0 1 0
[3,] 0 0 1
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Look into the `dimnames` argument to `matrix`: a list with a vector for rownames (commonly `NULL`) and a vector for colnames.  Then do the same at the C++ level.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Newer versions of `Rcpp` provides `rownames()` and `colnames()` which function as their `R` counterparts do:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix test(NumericMatrix x)
{
    rownames(x) = CharacterVector::create("a", "b", "c");
    colnames(x) = CharacterVector::create("A", "B", "C");
    return x;
}

/*** R
test(matrix(1:9, nrow = 3))
*/
```

gives me

```
> test(matrix(1:9, nrow = 3))
  A B C
a 1 4 7
b 2 5 8
c 3 6 9
```